# When I select header or footer why it shows new window in header or footer.Actully I don't want to show window

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, interop

I designed one form which shows the text in document also text in header and footer. It works good for text rather than header and footer text. But when select text of header or footer from the form it selects that text in header or in footer, but it shows new window which contains scrollbar and close buttons. Such window I don't want to show.

Answer (score 0):

> But when select text of header or footer from the form it slects that
> text in header or in footer ,but it shows new window which contains
> scrollbar and close buttons.

That's your problem, you *selected* the text. You should always avoid selecting anything when working with Word.

Instead, you should refer to the object directly and use its `Range` property to access the text or other properties.